# Get several first row in excel by each categories

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Screenshot:
[image]

Halo everyone.
I need help for this case.
Case:
I have some data as you can see in the picture.  I want to make a new sheet that contain only first 5 row by each column "Kode Cabang". It means,"Kode Cabang 10600" has 5 row, "Kode Cabang 10600" has 5 row and so on.

Which formula should I use?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One could try using `MAP()` :

[image]

---

```
=FILTER(A1:B33,MAP(A1:A33,LAMBDA(x,COUNTIF(A1:x,x)))<=5)
```

---

One can use `POWER QUERY` as well, to use Power Query follow the steps:

[image]

---

- First convert the source ranges into a table and name it accordingly, for this example I have named it as `Table_One`

---

- Next, open a blank query from <kbd>Data</kbd> Tab --> <kbd>Get & Transform Data</kbd> --> <kbd>Get Data</kbd> --> <kbd>From Other Sources</kbd> --> <kbd>Blank Query</kbd>

---

- The above lets the <kbd>Power Query</kbd> window opens, now from <kbd>Home</kbd> Tab --> <kbd>Advanced Editor</kbd> --> And paste the following <kbd>M-Code</kbd> by removing whatever you see, and press <kbd>Done</kbd>

---

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table_One"]}[Content],
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(Source, {"Kode Cabang"}, {{"All", each _, type table [Kode Cabang=number, DATA=number]}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "Custom", each Table.FirstN([All],5)),
    #"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Added Custom",{"Custom"}),
    #"Expanded Custom" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Removed Other Columns", "Custom", {"Kode Cabang", "DATA"}, {"Kode Cabang", "DATA"})
in
    #"Expanded Custom"
```

---

[image]

---

- Lastly, to import it back to <kbd>Excel</kbd> --> Click on <kbd>Close & Load</kbd> or <kbd>Close & Load To</kbd> --> The first one which clicked shall create a <kbd>New Sheet</kbd> with the required output while the latter will prompt a window asking you where to place the result.

---

Comment: @BalaikotaSelf, you may want to use an helper column using the same technique (`COUNTIF()`), or use PowerQuery (Groupby>Apply Table.FirstN>Expand).

Answer (score 4):

Give a try to the following formula-

```
=REDUCE(A1:B1,UNIQUE(A2:A23),LAMBDA(a,x,VSTACK(a,TAKE(FILTER(A2:B23,A2:A23=x),5))))
```

[image]

Comment: thank you so much Sir, but unfortunately my excel doesn't have REDUCE Function

Comment: @BalaikotaSelf Then you may need a helper column? Does your excel version support `FILTER()` function?